# How to do variadic deduction in std::function's parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I try to implement a function f: (std::function -> int) which will pass 1s into `input_functor`
with c++ variadic template.

Let input_functor be g.

For example:

- If g is `std::function<int(int,int)>`, then f return `g(1, 1)`.
- If g is `std::function<int(int,int,int)>`, then f return `g(1, 1, 1)`.
- If g is `std::function<int(int,int,int,int)>`, then f return `g(1, 1, 1, 1)`.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
int apply(std::function<int(T, Args...)> func) {
    auto tmp = [func](Args... args) {
        return func(1, args...);
    };
    return apply(tmp);
}

template <typename T>
int apply(std::function<int(T)> func) {
    return func(1);
}

int main() {
    std::function<int(int, int)> f = [](int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    };
    std::cout << apply(f) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (clang++) error msg is that it cannot match candidates.

```
main.cpp:9:12: error: no matching function for call to 'apply'
    return apply(tmp);
           ^~~~~
main.cpp:21:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'apply<int, int>' requested here
    std::cout << apply(f) << "\n";
                 ^
main.cpp:5:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<int (type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1...)>' against
      '(lambda at main.cpp:6:16)'
int apply(std::function<int(T, Args...)> func) {
    ^
main.cpp:13:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<int (type-parameter-0-0)>' against '(lambda at main.cpp:6:16)'
int apply(std::function<int(T)> func) {
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: You probably need to explicitly specify the type for `tmp`, you can't deduce `std::function` template arguments from a lambda. Alternatively it might be simpler to explicitly specify the type for the recursive call to `apply`

Comment: Not sure the compiler will be able to optimise away all the std::functions though, code could be a bit slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

- definition order:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  int apply(std::function<int(T)> func) {
      return func(1);
  }
  ```

  should be place before the recursive function to allow to be visible and ends recursion.
- lambda is not a `std::function`, so deduction don't happen

  ```
  template <typename T, typename... Args>
  int apply(std::function<int(T, Args...)> func) {
      auto tmp = std::function{[func](Args... args) { // C++17 CTAD
          return func(1, args...);
      }};
      return apply(tmp);
  }
  ```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fKEfq5) C++17

As you are limited to C++11, you might create traits to know which `std::function` is needed:

```
template <typenate T, typename Discarded>
struct always_first
{
    using type = T;
};
template <typenate T, typename Discarded> using always_first_t = typename always_first<T, Discarded>::type;

// possibly directly
// template <typenate T, typename Discarded> using always_first_t = T;
// but old compilers might have some issues with that construct as std::void_t
```

and then

```
std::function<int(always_first_t<int, Args>...)> tmp = /* your lambda */;
```